# Countering mordekaiser

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you counter Mordekaiser?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3191/how-do-you-counter-mordekaiser)

Which champion is the best to counter mordekaiser? Lately I've been finding mordekaiser probably the hardest solo top opponents and I'd really like some advice on countering him.

Answer (score 0):

In the mid lane i would say Ryze, Cassiopea, Galio and Lee sin early game....
As for the strategy you have to try to outrange him and try to keep his shield down and when he gets his shield up keep clear of him and rush a hextech revolver because sustain vs him is very very very nice