# How do I effectively lane against Mordekaiser?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you counter Mordekaiser?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3191/how-do-you-counter-mordekaiser)

I'm having a lot of trouble laning against Mordekaiser. I feel that his shield is always up to prevent harass, and his harass is just too much.  Any tips or champions I should pick against him?

Answer (score 0):

Ryze and Cass both do really well vs him. They have quite a bit higher range and can really blow him up between minion waves while his shield is down then when the minion waves are there for him to shield off of they can safely farm from a distance.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest single counter to Mordekaiser is Zilean.  In lane, Zilean won't beat Mordekaiser, however, if the game goes to team fighting, he's a direct counter to Mordekaiser's ultimate.  There are many champions however that can easily lane against him and simply provide more for a team in almost every situation.  Morgana, Cho'Gath, Gragas, and Galio are four really strong examples of champions that can lane against Mordekaiser fairly easily.  They also provide much better crowd control effects to support your team.

Another strong way to shut down Mordekaiser is with early ganks.  Pre-nerf Nunu was quite obnoxious to deal with as Mordekaiser.  Nowadays, Lee Sin is probably the biggest threat to Mordekaiser's early game.

Source: http://www.lolpro.com/guides/mordekaiser/103-mordekaiser-guide-mid-lane/tips-tricks-synergies-and-counters